# ActiveRecord sum and pluck method return strange value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Order model and `Order.all` returns below.

```
[
[0] #<Order:0x007f9d9e236de0> {
              :id => 15,
         :user_id => 2,
       :artist_id => nil,
      :address_id => 18,
         :paid_at => nil,
    :payment_type => "bank",
            :guid => "c8e22764774adc6825348b8874b581e8",
      :created_at => Mon, 24 Aug 2015 19:42:09 JST +09:00,
      :updated_at => Mon, 24 Aug 2015 19:45:38 JST +09:00,
      :ordered_at => Mon, 24 Aug 2015 19:45:37 JST +09:00,
           :total => 43890
},
[1] #<Order:0x007f9d9e2367a0> {
              :id => 12,
         :user_id => 2,
       :artist_id => nil,
      :address_id => 18,
         :paid_at => nil,
    :payment_type => "bank",
            :guid => "274b4a8653395023125a4724139efc09",
      :created_at => Mon, 24 Aug 2015 19:10:38 JST +09:00,
      :updated_at => Mon, 24 Aug 2015 19:41:25 JST +09:00,
      :ordered_at => Mon, 24 Aug 2015 19:41:22 JST +09:00,
           :total => 48689
},
[2] #<Order:0x007f9d9e236318> {
              :id => 11,
         :user_id => 2,
       :artist_id => nil,
      :address_id => 14,
         :paid_at => Mon, 24 Aug 2015 19:10:38 JST +09:00,
    :payment_type => "credit_card",
            :guid => "b075f4a6f31c32942152f7d50d2bd098",
      :created_at => Mon, 24 Aug 2015 19:03:39 JST +09:00,
      :updated_at => Mon, 24 Aug 2015 19:10:38 JST +09:00,
      :ordered_at => Mon, 24 Aug 2015 19:10:38 JST +09:00,
           :total => 5010
},
[3] #<Order:0x007f9d9e235e40> {
              :id => 10,
         :user_id => nil,
       :artist_id => nil,
      :address_id => nil,
         :paid_at => nil,
    :payment_type => nil,
            :guid => "916ff17977cb176c5e5740faab92a08c",
      :created_at => Sat, 22 Aug 2015 19:30:38 JST +09:00,
      :updated_at => Sat, 22 Aug 2015 19:30:38 JST +09:00,
      :ordered_at => nil,
           :total => 0
},
[4] #<Order:0x007f9d9e2356c0> {
              :id => 9,
         :user_id => 1,
       :artist_id => nil,
      :address_id => 9,
         :paid_at => nil,
    :payment_type => "bank",
            :guid => "a4f1dd11ad035d1747a37776b062021f",
      :created_at => Sat, 22 Aug 2015 19:30:04 JST +09:00,
      :updated_at => Tue, 01 Sep 2015 00:00:09 JST +09:00,
      :ordered_at => Sat, 22 Aug 2015 00:00:00 JST +09:00,
           :total => 5010
},
[5] #<Order:0x007f9d9e2342c0> {
              :id => 8,
         :user_id => 1,
       :artist_id => nil,
      :address_id => 9,
         :paid_at => Thu, 20 Aug 2015 19:30:04 JST +09:00,
    :payment_type => "credit_card",
            :guid => "b816503b6b95d35455262cd4d8b9e822",
      :created_at => Sat, 22 Aug 2015 19:30:04 JST +09:00,
      :updated_at => Sat, 22 Aug 2015 19:30:04 JST +09:00,
      :ordered_at => Wed, 19 Aug 2015 19:30:04 JST +09:00,
           :total => 0
}
```

]

However, `Order.sum(:total)` returns

```
Order.sum(:total)
(0.4ms)  SELECT SUM("orders"."total") FROM "orders"
12000
```

and `Order.pluck(:total)` returns

```
Order.pluck(:total)
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "orders"."total" FROM "orders"  ORDER BY   "orders"."created_at" DESC
[
    [0] nil,
    [1] nil,
    [2] nil,
    [3] nil,
    [4] 2000,
    [5] 10000
]
```

So, what happened?
How can I get correct value?

Thanks many comments.

I have default scope, but only order,

```
   default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
```

. Is this affect this probrem??

This is 'Order.all' query.

```
Order Load (1.0ms) SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY "orders"."created_at" DESC 
Item Load (0.4ms) SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."order_id" = $1 [["order_id", 20]] 
Flower Load (0.7ms) SELECT "flowers".* FROM "flowers" WHERE "flowers"."type" IS NULL AND "flowers"."item_id" = $1 ORDER BY "flowers"."created_at" ASC LIMIT 1 [["item_id", 8]]
```

`Order.all.map(&:total)` returns

```
[ [ 0] 43890, [ 1] 48689, [ 2] 5010, [ 3] 0, [ 4] 5010, [ 5] 0 ]
```

---

sorry for the delay in reply...

This is my result for orders.html.erb,
and I use only myapp_development and myapp_test databases.

```
Order.count 6
Order.sum(:total)   12,000
Order.pluck(:total) [nil, nil, 2000, 10000, nil, nil]
Order.all.map(&:total)  [0, 5010, 0, 0, 16110, 0]
#<Order id: 6, user_id: 1, artist_id: nil, address_id: nil, paid_at: nil, payment_type: nil, guid: "a6471c15680a0fbcd3f515a1bdf83566", created_at: "2015-09-02 07:24:37", updated_at: "2015-09-02 07:24:37", ordered_at: nil, total: nil, conveni_name: nil, conveni_code: nil, invoice_id: nil>

#<Order id: 5, user_id: 1, artist_id: nil, address_id: 14, paid_at: "2015-09-02 07:24:36", payment_type: 0, guid: "b68989c73bc0af34e3eef56abbcb306c", created_at: "2015-09-01 08:58:07", updated_at: "2015-09-02 07:24:36", ordered_at: "2015-09-02 07:24:36", total: nil, conveni_name: nil, conveni_code: nil, invoice_id: nil>

#<Order id: 4, user_id: 1, artist_id: nil, address_id: 1, paid_at: nil, payment_type: 2, guid: "1863cc6f2884b88598c4524d564b8a4a", created_at: "2015-09-01 06:07:52", updated_at: "2015-09-01 06:07:52", ordered_at: "2015-08-31 15:00:00", total: 2000, conveni_name: nil, conveni_code: nil, invoice_id: nil>

#<Order id: 3, user_id: 1, artist_id: nil, address_id: 1, paid_at: "2015-08-30 06:07:52", payment_type: 0, guid: "a6f7e22fc9ea8bdccdbdcbb00d9ea250", created_at: "2015-09-01 06:07:52", updated_at: "2015-09-01 06:07:52", ordered_at: "2015-08-29 06:07:52", total: 10000, conveni_name: nil, conveni_code: nil, invoice_id: nil>

#<Order id: 2, user_id: 1, artist_id: nil, address_id: 11, paid_at: "2015-09-01 08:58:06", payment_type: 0, guid: "f29dd23315078fce2e5b38e16d027c45", created_at: "2015-09-01 06:06:33", updated_at: "2015-09-01 08:58:06", ordered_at: "2015-09-01 08:58:06", total: nil, conveni_name: nil, conveni_code: nil, invoice_id: nil>

#<Order id: 1, user_id: nil, artist_id: nil, address_id: nil, paid_at: nil, payment_type: nil, guid: "6f2ffd0e8ba491fba10d69b73e717384", created_at: "2015-09-01 03:08:44", updated_at: "2015-09-01 03:08:44", ordered_at: nil, total: nil, conveni_name: nil, conveni_code: nil, invoice_id: nil>
```

Comment: have you got a default scope on the `Order` model?

Comment: @japed If OP have some default scopes also.. Why then it is not working with `sum` method.

Comment: OP has posted the queries as well. If he had default scope we should be seeing them in the query atleast.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I agree

Comment: Can you post the query when you run Order.all

Comment: Stupid question, but you're definitely looking at the same database in both cases, right?  I mean one of them isn't from your test database or something?

Comment: What do you get from `Order.all.map(&:total)`?

Comment: Also, what does the `Order` model look like?

Comment: I have default scope, but only order, `  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }`.  Is this affect this probrem??

Comment: `Order.all` Order Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders"  ORDER BY "orders"."created_at" DESC
  Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 20]]
  Flower Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "flowers".* FROM "flowers" WHERE "flowers"."type" IS NULL AND "flowers"."item_id" = $1  ORDER BY "flowers"."created_at" ASC LIMIT 1  [["item_id", 8]]

Comment: `Order.all.map(&:total)` returns `[
    [ 0] 43890,
    [ 1] 48689,
    [ 2] 5010,
    [ 3] 0,
    [ 4] 5010,
    [ 5] 0
]` !!

Comment: Have you got a method that redefines total on the Order model?

Comment: show your Order model please.

Comment: @myoo can you please validate once again what is output of `Order.all.inspect`?

Comment: @myoo can you please provide us with more information (see my answer below) or you aren't interested?

Comment: Could you post your Order model too?

Answer (score 6):

Information you provide is contradictory.

I think you look at different databases.

Let me explain why I think so.

**Fact #1** Based on `Order.all` output we have:

```
#<Order id: 15, total: 43890.0>
#<Order id: 12, total: 48689.0>
#<Order id: 11, total: 5010.0>
#<Order id: 10, total: 0.0>
#<Order id: 9,  total: 5010.0>
#<Order id: 8,  total: 0.0>
```

`total` attribute here is identical to what is written in database. Even if you have method with the same name defined in `Order` model, this attribute should not be affected by it.

**Fact #2** Based on `Order.pluck(:total)` output we have:

```
#<Order id: 15, total: nil>
#<Order id: 12, total: nil>
#<Order id: 11, total: nil>
#<Order id: 10, total: nil>
#<Order id: 9,  total: 2000>
#<Order id: 8,  total: 10000>
```

Again, `total` attribute here is identical to what is written in database. And again it's not affected by methods defined in your model.

Now we see **Fact 1** contradicts **Fact 2**. I'm almost sure you are looking at different databases here.

The best way to be sure that you don't get contradictory results is to create a new page with this content inside:

```
<!-- orders.html.erb -->

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Order.count</td>
    <td><%= Order.count %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Order.sum(:total)</td>
    <td><%= number_with_delimiter Order.sum(:total) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Order.pluck(:total)</td>
    <td><%= Order.pluck(:total) %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Order.all.map(&amp;:total)</td>
    <td><%= Order.all.map(&:total) %></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<% Order.all.each do |o| %>
  <p>
    <code><%= o.inspect %></code>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and give us output from this page for further exploration.

Basically what I ask for:

1. Check you are not working with two different databases
2. If #1 was useless, create a new action with given ERB template and share it's output.

Answer (score 4):

If `Order.pluck(:total)` returns something different than `Order.all.map(&:total)`, then the 'total' method might be defined somewhere and thus overwrites the column attribute method. You can check the source filename and line of this method via:

```
Order.new.method(:total).source_location
```

It should reference `activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb`. If it doesn't, then this is where you've accidentially overwritten the ActiveRecord method.

Comment: I doubt this is the reason. Comparing `Order.all` and `Order.pluck(:total)` outputs it looks more like he's looking at different databases.